Proof that if W is the image of a Unitary operator with an $n^O(1)$ size quantum circuit, then $R_W$ has an $n^O(1)$ circuit as well
I have been working on the following problem
Suppose $H$ is the Hilbert space of n qubits. Let $W_0$ be the subspace of $H ⊗ H$ with basis $|x_0⟩$, x = 0,...,N −1 where $N = 2^n$. Suppose $U$ is a unitary operator on $H⊗H$. Let $W$ be the image of $W_0$ under $U$. Show that if $U$ has $n^{O(1)}$-size quantum circuit. Then $R_W$ , reflection through $W$ , also has $n^{O(1)}$-size quantum circuit.
Here, $R_W$ is the reflection through the subspace $W$, given by $2 \Sigma_{I=1}^m |w_i \rangle \langle w_i| - I$. I know that $R_W$ is a reflection operator and that it maps elements of $W$ to themselves, and it maps $|v \rangle \in W^{\perp}$ to $-|v \rangle$. I have been reading about Grover's algorithm and this reflection operator comes up a lot there, and have seen some applications that are related to Grover's algorithm where the qubits are prepared into the uniform state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \Sigma_{x=1}^N |x \rangle$ using Hadamard gates but I really have no idea how to go about this problem. I have been reading about Grover's algorithm, quantum gates and the reflection operators (along with other things like oracles etc.) but I don't know how to apply any of that to this problem. First, I am not sure why the size of $R_W$'s circuit is dependent on $U$, but even given that, I am not sure how this specific subspace ties into it either.
I have been working on this problem for a few days, but I am quite stuck as I don't have any intuition about why I should be doing what I am doing. I have read notes from multiple authors, practiced problems but I haven't encountered anything about proving the size of a circuit (and where $U$ comes into this at all). If anyone could provide any help or guidance on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Why not ask your TA for help first before posting it online?

I'm not sure if you actually want an answer, but it is Saturday night and since the next office hours are the day the assignment is due, I wanted to get ahead as I've been working on this for a while. I will ask my TA once the week starts but I don't think there's anything wrong with using multiple avenues.

You can just email your TA (which is me, fyi), and there is something wrong with using multiple avenues, as this is against the university's academic conduct policy.
